# Transform 1x4 matrix into a 4x1 matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to multiply two matrices in Python 3.x with numpy like this:

```
res = A.dot(vertice)
```

'A' beign a 4x4 matrix and 'vertice' beign a 1x4 matrix.

The problem is when I try running the program, I get the next error message:

```
ValueError: shapes (4, 4) and (1, 4) are not alligned: 4 (dim1) != 1 (dim0)
```

As far as I know, the only way to multiply two matrices by having the same number of columns in matrix 1 as the number of rows in matrix 2.

Can you give me some advice on how to transform the 'vertice' matrix to a 4x1 one?

Thanks

Comment: The rule is last dim * 2nd to last. You go across the columns of the 1st, and down the rows of the 2nd.  `transpose` is your friend `vertice.T`.

Comment: `res = A.dot(vertice.T)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate transpose:

```
res = A.dot(vertice.T)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need code you can try
    B = np.mat(B) 
    C = np.mat(C)

```
A = B.T*C.I
```